# ¿Cómo ordenar esta consulta sql con union?

Tags: php, sql

Necesito ordenar una consulta por un campo que tengo en la tabla llamado orden, pero por mucho que lo he intentado no se ordenan, siempre se ordenan por id. Si realizo una consulta si el UNION se ordenan perfectamente por orden.

¿Qué puede estar sucediendo? A ver si me podéis echar una mano.

```
$sql= "


(SELECT rop, idF, year FROM cot WHERE rop!='1' AND year='1998' ORDER BY orden ASC  LIMIT 1 )

 UNION

( SELECT rop, idF, year FROM cot WHERE rop!='1' AND ( year = '0' || year = ".$year.") ORDER BY orden ASC )


";
```

Al hacerlo de esta forma, me da un error (solución de @Fernando Forcén):

```
  $sql= "

    SELECT * FROM (  


    (SELECT rop, idF, year FROM cot WHERE rop!='1' AND year='1998' ORDER BY orden ASC  LIMIT 1 )

     UNION

    ( SELECT rop, idF, year FROM cot WHERE rop!='1' AND ( year = '0' || year = ".$year.") ORDER BY orden ASC )

    ) Datos ORDER BY orden

    ";
```

**Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in”**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías hacer una consulta por encima para ordenarlos:

```
SELECT *
FROM (    
(SELECT rop, idF, year, orden FROM cot WHERE rop!='1' AND year='1998' ORDER BY orden ASC  LIMIT 1 )

     UNION

    ( SELECT rop, idF, year, orden FROM cot WHERE rop!='1' AND ( year = '0' || year = ".$year.") ORDER BY orden ASC )
) Datos
ORDER BY orden
```

Comment: Error:

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ... on line 70

Siempre me da esos errores con las soluciones que he encontrado por la red, no entiendo el motivo.

¿Lo de Datos qué es? perdón por mi ignorancia.

Comment: ¿Has probado si la consulta funciona correctamente? Si es así, puedes probar a crear una vista con ella y utilizar la llamada a la vista en lugar de lanzar la SQL directamente.

Comment: Las consultas funcionan Fernando, pero es al ordenarlas cuando da error, o simplemente no se ordenan (se ordenan por id por defecto). Sin el union ambas consultas independientes también funcionan.

¿A qué te refieres con la llamada a la vista?

Comment: Lo de Datos es un alias para la subconsulta. Yo solo te he puesto la consulta, tu debería añadir lo que tenías antes: $sql= " por delante y "; por detrás..... eso debes seguir poniendolo.

Comment: Claro, he editado el post de mi duda con tu solución implementada. Da ese error que no sé a qué puede ser debido. :(

Al quitar lo del ORDER BY orden del final, funciona, pero salen sin ordenar.

Comment: Prueba a poner el campo entre comillas, así: ORDER BY `orden`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53235/discussion-between-fernando-forcen-and-playerwet).

Comment: Ya he dado con la solución Fernando. Había que incluír en las consultas SELECT la columna orden. No sé a qué puede ser debido, pero me he vuelto loco sin encontrar la solución. Por la red nadie indica este problema, al menos yo no lo he encontrado.

Fernando, para mejorar tu respuesta añade el carpo orden en las consultas select. De esta forma: SELECT rop, idF, year, orden ¿Sabrías por qué es necesario incluír el orden en las consultas? es rarísimo que sin el union no haga falta y con el unión sí jaja

Comment: Es verdad!!!! vi que lo tenías en la condición pero no en el resultado. Efectivamente, si tienes que aplicar un criterio o un orden sobre el resultado, el campo tiene que estar en los valores devuelto por las consultas. Edito la respuesta.

Comment: jaja me he vuelto loco sin saber porqué cascaba, qué barbaridad. Gracias Fernando.

Comment: Fernando ahora tengo otro problema, no me sale la primera consulta como primer registro, sale todo ordenado por orden. Me gustaría que estuviese primero el resultado de la primera consulta y luego la segunda por orden. Perdona por molestarte de nuevo.

Comment: pasate al chat para no hacer esto más largo

Answer (score 1):

Respuesta que me funciona perfectamente en Mysql

```
(select * from tabla1 where condicion='dato')
UNION ALL
(select * from tabla2 where condicion='otrodato')
ORDER BY valorx desc, valory asc
```

En el fondo no hay que ordenar las dos consultas que estan entre paréntesis, solo ordenar al final.